# Transcend External hard disk: continuous beeping

Tags: external-hard-drive, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

I have a 500GB Transcend StoreJet external HDD. The problem is it beeps for long time. When it beeps I can not access the drive. Even sometime I can, I dont see full file listing or empty folder!
It just beeps and beeps. Never stops. Sometimes removing the USB cable and attaching it again makes the sound goes away. But it does not work all time.

The hard disk has no warranty. It just expired 2-3 weeks ago.

Why is this happening? Is my drive faulty? If *yes* how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried it on a different port or computer? Also try a different cable. Does it have its own power supply? If not then you might want to try a y-cable to ensure that it's getting enough power (unless it's USB 3.0).

Comment: Its USB 3.0. It has separate power cable. I am have tried from front panel USB ports.

Comment: Never mind! I have fixed it. Sharing my answer bellow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this continuous beep is hardware failure. Specially if the disk motor is not running or the spindle can not spin etc. The main reason for such failure is lack of power.

**Putting it in the rear mother board panel will solve the problem as it will surely powered up by proper amperage on 5 volt line.**

Another option is to **use a USB hub which have external power supply**. I have such hub. I have been using this hard drive on that hub for about 3 years. Recently I just turned off my hub and put the HDD in front panel. So the problem arose. Now its okay as I connect it again.

Comment: I am glad that my suggestion of using a different port worked for you. But I think your question was a little unclear as you mentioned that the warranty had just expired, suggesting that you had had used the drive for some time without problems.

Comment: yes, I have been using this for 3 years. And warranty period is 3 years. It worked the whole time, But I never notice that I am using an external powered USB hub. Even After I used it in front panel I dind't get any beep for some days. In fact I am getting beeps for 6-7 days. and today the drive was not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

my armored 500gb Transcend requires a double USB cord- that means it's got a male mini USB on one end and TWO standard male USBs on the other end.  if you connect it to your computer with a standard 'one mini USB to one standard USB' cord like you use for dozens of other devices, you are only feeding it half the power it needs and it will just beep at you. if you can't find the cord I don't know if a powered USB hub will help unless it automatically feeds it the required voltage- which it may...I've never worked with them.  hope you got this fixed, I'm just posting this for other beeping Transcend external drive users.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had a proble like that, it was a Seagate 1tb 3, 5 fitted on external usb case, I took the disk out, shaked it strongly ( be careful not to drop it) and heard a click, then plugged it in and worked ok.

Comment: This could damage the disk further...

Answer (score -3):

Mine had the same problem, it was one of those military-grade shock-proof HDDs.
Threw it around the room, reconnected it after every throw, and it's started working again.
Only did it because it didn't have any important files though :p

Comment: My HDD is not military grade shock proof also I have important files in it.